# mod_wsgi | linux installation error

Tags: linux, mod-wsgi

I'm getting the following error when I try to install mod_wsgi

```
./configure

checking for apxs2... no
checking for apxs... /usr/sbin/apxs
checking Apache version... 2.2.3
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile

make

/usr/sbin/apxs -c -I/usr/local/include/python2.6 -DNDEBUG   mod_wsgi.c -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib/python2.6/config  -lpython2.6 -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm
/apr-1/build/libtool --silent --mode=compile gcc -prefer-pic -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i386 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fno-strict-aliasing  -DLINUX=2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -pthread -I/usr/include/httpd  -I/usr/include/apr-1   -I/usr/include/apr-1  -I/usr/local/include/python2.6 -DNDEBUG  -c -o mod_wsgi.lo mod_wsgi.c && touch mod_wsgi.slo
sh: /apr-1/build/libtool: No such file or directory
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=8323072
.
make: *** [mod_wsgi.la] Error 1
```

libtool is installed on my system..

**mod_wsgi 3.2**
****Apache 2.2****
****Python 2.6****

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're possibly missing apr development files. Depending on your distribution check your package manager for 'apr'. On ubuntu it might be 'libaprutil1-dev'.

Comment: Just to be shure. You're trying to compile -not install- mod_wsgi (?) Compiling needs development files i.e. headers. For example on Ubuntu there is 'libaprutil1' which is the runtime files, and 'libaprutil1-dev' which you need for compiling things against it. Which distribution are you using?